Can you solve this statistical gravitational integro-differential equation?
The short version:
$y$, $r$, and $C$ are real and positive.  $C$ is a constant.  Is there a solution to this?
$$y\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^{2}y\frac{dy}{dr}\right)=-C$$
The backstory:
It's a rough day when you can't solve a math problem, so you decide to solve the trivial case first, but then you can't solve that either.
What is the density distribution of a spherically symmetric cloud of infinitesimal particles bound by their mutual gravity? I'm starting with the trivial case, in which all the particles have the same energy per mass $E$ and same angular momentum per mass $L=0$. So every particle just oscillates straight through the center, then stops and turns back down at some $r_{max}$. G is the gravitational constant, density $p(r)$ is the mass of particles within the spherical shell between $r$ and $r+dr$, $p(r>r_{max})=0$, $M\equiv\int_{0}^{r_{max}}p(r')dr'$ is the total mass of the cloud, and U(r) is the potential energy at radius r. The system is at dynamic equilibrium so $p(r)$ is constant in time.
The method I'm trying is to calculate $U$ in terms of $p$, calculate $p$ in terms of $U$, then combine to get a diffeq for $U$.
The gravitational acceleration at $r$ is proportional to the total mass inside the spherical volume of radius $r$:
$$a(r)=-\frac{GM}{r^{2}}\int_{0}^{r}p(r')dr'$$
And so, U(r) can be calculated from the force$\times$distance integral from infinity:
$$U(r>r_{max})=\int_{\infty}^{r}\frac{GM}{r'^{2}}dr'=-\frac{GM}{r}$$
$$U(r_{max})=-\frac{GM}{r_{max}}$$
$$U(r<r_{max})=U(r_{max})+\int_{r_{max}}^{r}\frac{G}{r'^{2}}\int_{0}^{r'}p(r'')dr''dr'$$
The method I'm trying is to calculate U in terms of p, calculate p in terms of U, then combine to get a diff eq for U.
The energy (per mass) equation is:
$$E=U(r)+\frac{1}{2}v(r)^{2}$$
But the oscillating particles stop at $r_{max}$ so,
$$E=U(r_{max})=-\frac{GM}{r_{max}}$$
and therefore $$r_{max}=-\frac{GM}{E}$$
The radial velocity of particles at r tells how long particles spend at r.
$$v(r)=(2E-2U(r))^{1/2}$$
$$\frac{dt}{dr}=(2E-2U(r))^{-1/2}$$
Integrating over the full range of r gives us the length of a quarter period.
$$T(U)=4\int_{0}^{r_{max}}(2E-2U(r))^{-1/2}dr$$
Note that $T$ is a functional of $U$, independent of $r$.
The density $p(r)$ is the mass $M$ times the fraction of the orbital period spent making four oscillatory passes through $r$.
$$p(r)=4M\frac{dt/dr}{T(U)}=4M\frac{(2E-2U(r))^{-1/2}}{T(U)}$$
We combine equations:
$$U(r<r_{max})=E+\frac{4GM}{T(U)}\int_{r_{max}}^{r}\frac{1}{r'^{2}}\int_{0}^{r'}(2E-2U(r''))^{-1/2}dr''dr'$$
And there is the wall I hit with on this deceptively simple problem. I'm not sure if it helps, but we can make it look better by taking derivatives:
$$\frac{dU}{dr}=\frac{4GM}{T}\frac{1}{r^{2}}\int_{0}^{r}(2E-2U(r'))^{-1/2}$$
$$\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^{2}\frac{dU}{dr}\right)=\frac{4GM}{T}(2E-2U(r))^{-1/2}$$
If we substitute $y(r)\equiv\sqrt{E-U(r)}$ then we have
$$y\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^{2}y\frac{dy}{dr}\right)=-\frac{\sqrt{2}GM}{T}$$
where T is now a functional of y independent of r.
Is there any solution to that?

This equation is of the form $y^2y''+y(y')^2+f(x)y^2y'+g(x)=0$. If only it was of the form $y^2y''+2y(y')^2+f(x)y^2y'+g(x)=0$. Absolutely unfortunate :(

Yeah you are right. I read it too fast and shallowly and missed several things. I have now gone through the argument in detail and the result looks perfectly correct to me. I also rederived it using the full Boltzmann equation and got exactly the same result. Doubt the ODE has an analytical solution, but I am able to solve the system numerically. The shape of the solution is very roughly given by $p \approx \frac{M}{R}\cdot \frac{0.54x^{0.12}}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ where $x = r/R$ (good to $\sim 4%$ on most of the interval).

@Winther  Thanks for the insights.  This problem is a killer.  I had actually planned to figure out the density p(r) for an arbitrary distribution of p(E,L) and then find the p(E,L) that maximized the entropy.  But that was too hard so I tried this "trivial" case, but it turned out to be too hard too!

Well pure analytical solutions do not exist for the wast amounts of interesting problems. So even if this happens to be one that do not exist here then still by deriving the ODE you solved the hard part of the problem. Finding the solution from this is fairly easy numerically and that is solving it (one can also "construct" the solution by dropping particles one by one and letting the system relax). If you really need an analytical solution you can always find an approximation that is “good enough” from the numerical solution.

The next problem is a few steps up in complexity. I would look at the literature as these things have for sure been studied at some point. For example https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.1849 ; https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.01384 ; https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.08994 might be useful/interesting.
